# Populate stackpanel dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to automatically generate a known number of textboxes inside a stack panel which is inside a grid.row? In order to be a bit more explicit, I'll explain the expected functioning.

The user will input a number at the beginning of the program. Then, the same number of textbox will be automatically created in a precise location (stackpanel inside a grid row).

Comment: The usual way to do this sort of thing commercially would bind a list<string> to the itemssource of an itemscontrol in that grid row. Then template each item in that list into textboxes.  If string is too simplistic then build a viewmodel for each implementing inotifypropertychanged and with a string property plus whatever else you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop to create the `TextBoxes` and add them to the `Child` collection of the `StackPanel`, e.g.:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out int input))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Text = i.ToString() };
            stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtInput"/>

<Grid>
    ...
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackPanel" />
    ...
```